# Printing an array within double quotes

Tags: perl, syntax

```
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5);

print @a;      #output: 12345

print "\n";

print "@a";    #output: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Printing an array by putting its name withing double quotes puts a space between each index's value at output. How does it do it? Why doesn't `print @a;` prints the same? What's the need of both types? I mean when will you use `print @a;` instead of `print "@a";` and vice versa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even better question: Why doesn't it print something like *array{0x1232ef}*. Print is suppose to print a string output and `@a` isn't a scalar.

Heck, even better: This is a scalar context, so why not print `5` which is the number of elements in the array. This is how:

```
print scalar @a;
```

would print.

Instead, the `print` command is taking some liberties to try to do what you intended and not what you said you want.

Let's take a look at this little program:

```
@a = qw(a b c d e);

print "@a";         #prints "a b c d e"
print "\n";

print @a;           #prints "abcde"
print "\n";

print @a . "\n";    #prints "5"

print scalar @a;    #prints "5"
```

Notice that `print @a` prints `abcde`, but if I add a `\n` on the end, it then prints `@a` in a scalar context.

Take a look at the [Perldoc on print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) (try the command `perldoc -f print`. On most systems, the entire Perl documentation is available via `perldoc`)

```
* print LIST
* print

Prints a string or a list of strings. Returns true if successful[...]
```

Ah! If given a list, it'll print a list of strings.

> The current value of **$,** (if any) is printed between each LIST item. The current value of **$\** (if any) is printed after the entire LIST has been printed. Because print takes a LIST, anything in the LIST is evaluated in list context, including any subroutines whose return lists you pass to print.

Let's try a new program:

```
@a = qw(a b c d e);

$, = "--";
print "@a";         #prints "a b c d e"
print "\n";

print @a;           #prints "a--b--c--d--e"
print "\n";

print @a . "\n";    #prints "5"

print scalar @a;    #prints "5"
```

Hmmm... The `$,` added the double dashes between the list elements, but it didn't affect the `@a` in quotes. And, if `$,` is mentioned in the `perldoc`, why is everyone prattling about `$"`?

Let's take a look at [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

```
* $LIST_SEPARATOR
* $"

When an array or an array slice is interpolated into a double-quoted string or a
similar context such as /.../ , its elements are separated by this value. Default
is a space. For example, this:

print "The array is: @array\n";

is equivalent to this:

print "The array is: " . join($", @array) . "\n";

Mnemonic: works in double-quoted context.
```

So, that explains everything!

The default of `$"` is a single space, and the default of `$,` is null. That's why we got what we got!

One more program...

```
@a = qw(a b c d e);

$, = "--";
$" = "++";
print "@a";         #prints "a++b++c++d++e"
print "\n";

print @a;           #prints "a--b--c--d--e"
print "\n";

print @a . "\n";    #prints "5"
print scalar @a;    #prints "5"
```

Answer (score 9):

When an array is interpolated in a string, the assumption is you may want to be able to visually distinguish elements;  when you print a list, the assumption is you just want that data output contiguously.  Both are configurable; [$,](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24,) (default '') is inserted between elements of a list being printed, while [$"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%22) (default ' ') is inserted between elements of an array interpolated into a string.

Answer (score 6):

In the first instance, you are passing a list of arguments to `print`, and each is printed in turn.

In the second, you are interpolating an array into a string, and then printing the result.
When an array in interpolated in a string, the values are separated by `$"`, which defaults to .

Answer (score 1):

When Perl sees an array in an interpolated string, it rewrites it using join:

```
print "@array";
```

becomes

```
print join($" => @array);
```

by default, the value of `$"` is equal to a single space.

You can configure this behavior by localizing a change to `$"`

```
print "@array";     # '1 2 3 4 5'
{
    local $" = '';  # "
    print "@array"; # '12345'
}
print "@array";     # '1 2 3 4 5'
```

You can see how Perl rewrites your interpolated strings using the `-q` option of the core `B::Deparse` module:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-q -e 'print "@array"'
print join($", @array);
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 1):

### Array in double quotes

The [“Array Interpolation” section of the perldata documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Array-Interpolation) explains how the intercalated spaces in the value of `"@a"` get there:

> Arrays and slices are interpolated into double-quoted strings by joining the elements with the delimiter specified in the `$"` variable (`$LIST_SEPARATOR` if `use English;` is specified), space by default. The following are equivalent:
>
> ```
> $temp = join($", @ARGV);  # " for benefit of StackOverflow hiliter
> system "echo $temp";
> system "echo @ARGV";
> ```

This means that `print "@a"` passes a *single* scalar argument to `print`. In contrast, `print @a` in your example passes five.

### Printing multiple values

The [perlfunc documentation on `print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) explains what `print` with a list of arguments.

> **`print LIST`**
>
> … The current value of `$,` (if any) is printed between each LIST item.

The [perlvar documentation on `$,`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2c) is

> **`Handle->output_field_separator( EXPR )`**
>   **`$OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR`**
>   **`$OFS`**
>   **`$,`**
>
> The output field separator for the print operator. If defined, this value is printed between each of print's arguments. Default is `undef`.
>
> Mnemonic: what is printed when there is a `,` in your `print` statement.

Because `$,` defaults to the undefined value, you're seeing `print` output its arguments with no separator. In explicit terms, the code from your question is equivalent to

```
print join("", @a);
```

### Why?

The difference in behavior isn't a special case for `print`. Arrays interpolate into all double-quoted strings [as described above](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Array-Interpolation). A quick survey of [Google code-search hits for `print "@...`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=print%5Cs%2B%5C%22@%20lang%3a%5Eperl%24%20lang%3a%5Eperl%24&type=cs) seems to indicate that a frequent use for `print "@foo"` is debugging output, as in

```
sub foo {
  print "args = @_\n" if $debug;
  ...;
}
```

A handy trick that Mark Dominus uses to provide visible separators for lists whose values may contain spaces is

```
sub foo {
  if ($debug) {
    local $" = "][";
    print "args = [@_];  # e.g., [foo][1][3.14159]
  }
  ...;
}
```

Say `@a` contains lines of output such as

```
@a = map "  - $_\n", @error_messages;
print @a;
```

Inserting implicit spaces between the values would hose my carefully constructed formatting:

```
  - sneaky-sneaky, sir
   - the hideousness of that foot will haunt my dreams forever
    - why would you do that?!
```

Perl tries hard to do what we mean, even when we're inconsistent in the demands we make.