# How can I get Perl string to keep its original formatting after editing it?

Tags: string, perl, encryption, split

I am attempting to write a code that will encrypt letters with a basic cyclic shift cipher while leaving any character that is not a letter alone. I am trying to do this through the use of a sub that finds the new value for each of the letters. When I run the code now,it formats the result so there is a single space between every encrypted letter instead of keeping the original formatting. I also cannot get the result to be only in lowercase letters.

```
sub encrypter {
        my $letter = shift @_;
        if ($letter =~ m/^[a-zA-Z]/) {
                $letter =~ y/N-ZA-Mn-za-m/A-Za-z/;
                return $letter;
                }
        else {

                return lc($letter);
        }
}
print "Input string to be encrypted: ";
my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
print "$input   # USER INPUT\n";
my @inputArray = split (//, $input);
my $i = 0;
my @encryptedArray;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $#inputArray; $i++) {
        $encryptedArray[$i] = encrypter($inputArray[$i]);
}
print "@encryptedArray   # OUTPUT\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how you are printing the array.

Change this line:

```
print "@encryptedArray   # OUTPUT\n";
```

to:

```
print join("", @encryptedArray) . "   # OUTPUT\n";
```

---

Here is an example that illustrates the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @array = ("a","b","c","d");

print "@array  # OUTPUT\n";
print join("", @array) . "  # OUTPUT\n";
```

Output:

```
$ perl test.pl
a b c d  # OUTPUT
abcd  # OUTPUT
```

---

According to the Perl documentation on [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html):

> The current value of $, (if any) is printed between each LIST item.
>   The current value of $\ (if any) is printed after the entire LIST has
>   been printed.

So two others ways to do it would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @array = ("a","b","c","d");
$,="";
print @array, "  #OUTPUT\n";
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @array = ("a","b","c","d");
$"="";
print @array, "  #OUTPUT\n";
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6586848/2534803) is a related answer and [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) is documentation explaining `$"` and `$,`.

Comment: The default value for `$,` is `undef`, so nothing is printed between print items and that value doesn't need to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Those spaces in your output from `$"` (list separator) because you use `print "@encryptedArray"` to print that array, which equals `print join($", @encryptedArray)`, therefore you could disable them by

```
local $" = '';
```

or you could join that `@encryptedArray` by yourself before you print it, just as suggested by @Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is no need for such complexity. `tr///` - also known as `y///` - wil convert the whole string for you. Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Input string to be encrypted: ";
chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);
print "$input   # USER INPUT\n";

(my $encrypted = $input) =~ tr/N-ZA-Mn-za-m/A-Za-z/;
print "$encrypted   # OUTPUT\n";
```